# Personal and Global messaging database design

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to implement a database design system that will be sending messages to a person(thus 1 to 1) or many persons (1 to many).

```
table --users
          |u_id | Name |
          | 01  | Aku  |
          | 02  | Sika |
          | 03  | Admin|

table --messages 
          |m_id | sender_id | Body   | Time |
          | 100 |  01       | hello  | 16:04|
          | 200 |  02       | Hi     | 16:08|
          | 300 |  03       | hi Guys| 19:12|

table --recipient
          |r_id| m_id | recipient_id| 
          | 50 | 100  |  02         |
          | 51 | 200  |  01         |
          | 52 | 300  |  01         |
          | 53 | 300  |  02         |

table --message_status
          |m_id | recipient_id | status | deleted |
          |100  |   02         | read   |  no     |
          |200  |   01         | unread |  no     |
          |300  |   01         | read   |  yes    |
          |300  |   02         | unread |  no     |
```

From my schema above, a user can send a message to one person and he can also send a message to many persons.Once a user sends a message to a person, we will have all the recipients `userid` in the `recipient` table as well as in the `message_status` table . So assuming a user is sending one message to 1 million users at a time, it means, there will be a 1 million rows in both the `recipient` and `message_status` table.

Please can there be a way to handle this by reducing the many insertion of rows when a user sends a message to many users or that is the right thing to do.

**NOTE**

Please the system should allow every recipient to delete a recieved message if he/she so wishes, however their delete should not affect other recipients. So if user with `u_id = 02` deletes her recieved message, user with `u_id=01` should still view his message.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Why not combine the `message_status` table and the `recipient` table?

Comment: @linger you stole the words right out of my mouth. `message_status` seems to contain all the info in `recipient`. You can't help large number of rows if you're tracking this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not combine the `message_status` table and the `recipient table`? Then you only update/insert one table instead of two.

**recipient:**

```
      |r_id| m_id | recipient_id|  status | deleted |
      | 50 | 100  |  02         |  read   |  no     |
      | 51 | 200  |  01         |  unread |  no     |
      | 52 | 300  |  01         |  read   |  yes    |
      | 53 | 300  |  02         |  unread |  no     |
```

Comment: well noted, but is it still right to allow many insertion when there is a one to many messaging

Comment: **@George**, Yes, it is.  If that is important information that needs to be tracked/kept.

Comment: Please don't you think it will slow performance, thus when there is an insertion of all these rows

Comment: Well hopefully 1 user of the system won't be sending one message to 1 million users at a time.  But yes, every database action has an impact on performance.  So, you create the best possible database structure for your needs.  Then make sure you have the proper hardware to support the load.

Comment: Very well. Thanks for your time and idea @Linger